# Generate an account number with sequence

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I need to generate an account number and insert it into a table column in the following format.
"TBA2222011300000001" = where "TBA" is the value of another column or user sent data "22220113" implies the current date and "00000001" is a seven digit sequence that needs to be incremented and appended for every insert.

How can I append the sequence to the column, Should I do it in java or can it be done at DB end. I am currently using postgres with java and spring boot.

Comment: "user sent data"? So the prefix may change during runtime?

Comment: "seven digit sequence" — Is this a sequence per prefix+date? So on the 30th we have a TBA2222011300000001 value, and on the next day the 31st we will have a TBA2222011310000001 value?

Comment: The sequence is incremented upon every insert to the database for eg: 00000001, 00000002 etc. No on the 30th we will have "TBA2222013000000001"

Answer (score 0):

Have an id column which is identity in postgres with start and end index as required.
For your reference to create identity column as desired
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/

Have 1 more column for createdDate.

Then account number is simply a derived value TBA + formatted(DATE) + formatted(Id).
Ex -
No not a trigger just a function. There won't be any account number column in your table. It will simply be a function which takes date and identity as input and gives account number as output. Since account number is only dependent on id and date. No need to store this value at all, whenever you need the account number just call that function. Account number will not exist at all. It will always be calculated based on id and date. Simple.

Refer this in the article
Method 1:  Derived Value called "markup"

The first method we may want to add to this table is a accountNumber method, for calculating our accountNumber based on current date and id.  Since this value will always be based on two other stored values, there is no sense in storing it (other than possibly in a pre-calculated index).  To do this, we:

```
CREATE FUNCTION accountNumber(id,date) RETURNS varchar AS
$$ SELECT TBA + format(id) + format(date)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

You need to put logic for format(id) and format(date) as per your requirement.

There is no point of storing the value which can be easily derived from other 2 columns. It would unnecessary consume space. Also maintaining data integrity and checks will be an overhead.

Creating function for derived values
https://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-2-intro-to.html

You can use the function in output as well as search.
Index would also be utilized as required.

Comment: So you want me to add a trigger in DB after every insert to append “TBA Date and sequence” and update the column value? I already have a serial column in the table, I doubt if we need another column just for incrementing. I also edited the question where TBA may not be constant always but it’s rare.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Also please refer  https://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-2-intro-to.html 
Method 1 in this article. It's explains clearly, no need of trigger or any other columns. Just the function will do the job. No overhead of anykind

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

> A generated column is a special column that is always computed from
> other columns.
> Several restrictions apply to the definition of
> generated columns and tables involving generated columns:
>
> - The generation expression can only use **immutable** functions and cannot use subqueries or reference anything other than the current row
>   in any way.

`now()` is mutable function, so you cannot use `Generated columns`.
I am not sure why `Default` not working.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html
So now the only option is trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE account_info(
    account_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    account_type text not null,
    acconut_number text ) ;
```

So what you want is to automate:

```
UPDATE account_info set 
    account_number = 
    concat(
        account_type,
        to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'),
        to_char(account_id, 'FM00000000'));
```

---

create the function

```
create or replace function update_account_number() returns trigger as $$
BEGIN
UPDATE account_info set 
    account_number = 
    concat(
        account_type,
        to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'),
        to_char(account_id, 'FM00000000'));
RETURN NULL; 
end;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgSQL;
```

create the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER udpate_accout_number
    AFTER INSERT ON account_info
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION update_account_number();
```

Comment: The only question that rises here, Are triggers expensive in DB?

Comment: @PragmaticFire I am not sure. Another option is store date in  a column, so you can catenate 3 columns easily.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to generate the desired account number.

1. Created a new sequence and appended zeros to it.

`select to_char(nextval('finance_accounts_id_seq'), 'fm00000000')`

2. Got the Current date in java using DateTimeFormatter

   DateTimeFormatter dmf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
   String date = LocalDate.now().format(dmf);
3. Got the "TBA" from request param of the user.